# Fuzzy string comparison to merge two lists

Tags: python, list, match, nltk, sublist

What's the most efficient way of extending one sublist with another sublist if they share a similar value at a particular index? I'd like to merge two sublists together if a value at index 0 of List1 is similar to the value of index 0 of List2.

```
List1 = [['V.H. Corp','b','c'],['Meredith Brands','e','f']]
List2 = [['VH Corporation','1','2'],['Meredith','3','4']]
```

I understand that it won't be perfect, but I need something that is good enough to match 'V.H. Corp' and 'VH Corporation' at the least.

Desired Output:

```
[['V.H. Corp','b','c','VH Corporation','1','2'],
 ['Meredith Brands','e','f','Meredith','3','4']]
```

This is what I have so far, which is not correct:

```
import nltk

def MergeSimilar(self,indice1,indice2,List1,List2):
    list2_keys = map(lambda x:x[indice2],List2)
    for i,l in enumerate(List1):
        if nltk.metrics.edit_distance(l[indice1],list2_keys) < 5:
            List1[i].extend(List2[list2_keys.index(l[indice1])]) 
    return List1
```

Faulty result:

```
>>> MergeSimilar(0,0,List1,List2)
[['V.H. Corp', 'b', 'c'], ['Meredith Brands', 'e', 'f']]
```

Comment: And what does what you have so far do?

Comment: why is it not correct ? (appart from the fact that edit distance for the first key appears to be ~9)

Comment: in your example, I would start by removing any non-letter, put that to lowercase, and see if one is included in the other

Comment: From [the docs](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.metrics.html#nltk.metrics.distance.edit_distance) it seems that `edit_distance` requires 2 strings, but your `list2_keys` is a list. Have you tried with a nested for loop?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to take all alphanumeric characters in lowercase for both lists and check if the two are within each other (as suggested by @njzk2). If you are using large lists (which I assume, as you are making this function), **make sure that you only do this operation once for each element** in the lists.

One way of doing this:

```py
import re

def MergeSimilar(idx1, idx2, list1, list2):
    dict2 = {re.sub(r'[\W_]+', '', l2[idx2].lower()): l2 for l2 in list2}
    for l1 in list1:
        simple1 = re.sub(r'[\W_]+', '', l1[idx1].lower())
        for simple2, l2 in dict2.items(): #use .iteritems() in python 2.x
            if simple1 in simple2 or simple2 in simple1:
                l1.extend(l2)
    return list1
```

Example use:

```py
List1 = [['V.H. Corp','b','c'],['Meredith Brands','e','f']]
List2 = [['VH Corporation','1','2'],['Meredith','3','4']]

print(MergeSimilar(0, 0, List1, List2))
#[['V.H. Corp', 'b', 'c', 'VH Corporation', '1', '2'], 
# ['Meredith Brands', 'e', 'f', 'Meredith', '3', '4']]
```